# How to describe homomorphism in terms of operations

Tags: terminology, abstract-algebra

I'm writing a paper, and in one section I discuss homomorphisms. As an example, I talk about the absolute value function as a homomorphism between the set of real numbers and the set of nonnegative real numbers. This homomorphism "supports" multiplication, of course:
$$ f(a \times b) = |a \times b| = |a| \times |b| = f(a) \times f(b) $$
Anyways, I'm trying to explain the relationship between this homomorphism and the multiplication operation in English.

I initially came up with "$f$ is *closed* under multiplication," but that's not quite correct because closure as a concept refers to sets, not maps. I've also seen language to the effect of "$f$ is a homomorphism that *preserves* multiplication." Is that right, or is there a more correct way of saying it?

If this question is better suited to english.SE, let me know.

Comment: "Preserves" is fine. $f$ is not a homomorphism of groups because $0$ does not have an inverse.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remove the part about groups.